# selectToUISlider error selectOptions[optIndex] is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

so I've got this function:

```
function load_question_div(render_to, question_info){

//alert(question_info);

var answertype = question_info['question']['answer_type'];
//var allow_graph = question_info['show_graph'];
var responseoptionset = question_info['response_option_set'];
var range = question_info['range'];
var labels = question_info['labels'];
var choices = question_info['choices'];

var questiondiv = $("#samplequestiondiv").clone();
$(questiondiv).attr("id", "question-div");
var questionform = $(questiondiv).children('form')[0];
$(questionform).attr('id', "question_form");
var questiontitle = $(questiondiv).children('p')[0];
$(questiontitle).text(question_info['question']['title']);

if(answertype == "slider"){
    var sliderdiv = document.createElement('div');
    $(sliderdiv).attr('id', "slider");
    $(sliderdiv).attr('style', "padding-top:1.5em;padding-right: 1em;padding-left:.5em;overflow: visible;");
    $(questionform).append(sliderdiv);
    for(var i=0; i<responseoptionset.length; i++){
        alert(responseoptionset[i]['id']);
        var qinput = document.createElement('div');
        $(qinput).addClass("question_input");
        $(qinput).attr("style", "text-align:center; margin-bottom:40px;padding-left:10px;");
        var inputlabel = document.createElement('label');
        $(inputlabel).text(responseoptionset[i]['text']);
        var inputselect = document.createElement('select');
        $(inputselect).attr('name', 'r'+responseoptionset[i]['id']);
        $(inputselect).attr('id', 'slider'+responseoptionset[i]['id']);
        for (var v=0; v< range.length; v++){
            var inputoption = document.createElement('option');
            $(inputoption).addClass("question_input");
            $(inputoption).attr('value', range[v]);
            $(inputselect).append(inputoption);
        }
        $(qinput).append(inputlabel);
        $(qinput).append(inputselect);
        $(questionform).append(qinput);
        alert("ok");
        $('#slider'+responseoptionset[i]['id']).selectToUISlider({tooltip: false, labels: labels}).hide();
        alert("done");
    }
```

this function is supposed to create a select, create options, and then create a selectToUISlider. When I comment out the "convert" statement (right before the last alert), everything appears as expected. When I leave it in, the appends don't work.

Furthermore, when I leave it in, nothing shows up and firebug gives me the error:

selectOptions[optIndex] is undefined
[Break On This Error]

(75 out of range 10)

I'm not sure where the 75 and 10 are coming from, but it's ALWAYS 75 and 10, no matter the range of my slider.

All of my variables are correct and as expected. 
I've done this before, almost the same way, except that I was using django template tags to create the elements, not jquery (and it worked).

I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 and jQueryUI 1.8.16 (as I was when it was working)

can anyone see the problem? Or has anyone run into this problem before?

Edit:
without the function call (which is the only way I can get the select to show up at all), the generated source for the select looks like:

```
<div style=
"padding-top: 1.5em; padding-right: 1em; padding-left: 0.5em; overflow: visible;" id=
"slider"></div>

<div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 10px;" class=
"question_input">
    <label>--</label>
    <select id="slider759" name="r759">
        <option text="1" value="1" class="question_input">
            1
        </option>

        <option text="2" value="2" class="question_input">
            2
        </option>

        <option text="3" value="3" class="question_input">
            3
        </option>

        <option text="4" value="4" class="question_input">
            4
        </option>

        <option text="5" value="5" class="question_input">
            5
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder: If you were to set the options' text fields, would the problem go away?

Comment: that did get rid of my error message, but now my selects aren't showing up.

Comment: Could you View Source and show the resulting HTML for just one of the selects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason it works if I select with the var name instead of the id.